# Mint Linux can't find unallocated ssd disk sapce

Tags: partitioning, installation, multi-boot, linux-mint

My laptop DELL PRECISION 3530 has 1 TB SSD. First I installed Windows 10 in 300 GB, and left the rest unallocated. I planned to install Mint Linux in the rest of the space.

When I boot Mint Linux by a Live USB and try to install it, it doesn't find unallocated space. It shows only 7 GB free space, not enough for mint installation. What is wrong and how to fix it?

Here is the output

```
mint@mint:~$ sudo sfdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.7 GiB, 1859526656 bytes, 3631888 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes    
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 7.5 GiB, 8074035200 bytes, 15769600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x39f675eb

 Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
 /dev/sda1  *          0 3793663 3793664  1.8G  0 Empty
```

[image]

Comment: Please run gparted from the Mint LiveUSB and do a screen capture of the drive sda. Screenshot that please, and upload that to imgur.com, then take the newly created link. Click on [edit] above and to the left, and show us what you find, please.

Comment: @K7AAY I *think* just adding an image here on stackexchange will upload it (somewhere) automatically. And @ masiboo, `fdisk -l (device)` or `sfdisk -l (device)` might be just as good, and the text can be pasted in easily (with code formatting if it looks better)

Comment: Since masiboo only has 103 pts, they may not have enough moxie to drag-and-drop images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the actual issue. It is mainly BIOS setup for the latest model laptops comes with UEFI and secure boot options. I had to follow the following options:

1. select UEFI enable it
2. Secure boot disable it.
3. QuickBoot/FastBoot disable it.
4. Intel Smart Response Technology (SRT) disable it.
5. SATA has multiple options. RAIDR, AHCI, etc. Select AHCI mode.

Then boot the Linux infestation by DVD or USB. Well, the latest laptop comes without any CD/DVD ROM.

Now you should see the whole SSD. To verify it just lunch GParted.