# No boot menu is show during bootup

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, boot, linux-mint

My laptop DELL PRECISION 3530 has 1 TB SSD. I installed 3 OS. First Windows 10, then Linux mint 19 and then Ubuntu 18. During the installation I had to straggle in the BIOS option. This laptop has option UEFI option. I didn't know anything about it. If UEFI and secure boot enable. When I bootup with the either Mint Linux or Ubuntu Linux, it doesn't show me my unallocated space. I was totally confused. Then I asked a question about it here:-
[Mint Linux can't find unallocated ssd disk sapce](https://superuser.com/questions/1373921/mint-linux-cant-find-unallocated-ssd-disk-sapce)

Anyway later I disable UEFI option and turn on legacy option in BIOS. After that I can see my total SSD and all space. Then I installed Mint and Ubuntu. But after installation. I was expecting that there will be a boot menu to select which OS to bootup. Now it doesn't show any boot menu at all. Here is pic of GParted :-

[image]

Please tell me how can I get the boot menu to boot any of the OS?

Comment: It's as simple as this: Windows 10 is in UEFI mode, the others in Legacy. The only way to choose between them is by changing UEFI ("BIOS") settings. Grub cannot boot other OSes in different modes  Always prefer UEFI mode, always. The drive not being accessible is unrelated to the installation mode.

Comment: Did you check my previous question that when I select UEFI mode, it doesn't show the unallocated SSD. That is why I was not able to install any other OS. Coz it shows I have only 8 GB free space available. But the reality is that 500+ GB unallocated space. Any idea what was wrong in UEFI mode.

Comment: Yes, of course. Two thing you should do to dual-boot: (1) In Windows, disable the Fast Startup feature and (2) in UEFI settings make sure the SATA mode is set to AHCI. However, before changing modes - if not in AHCI already - make sure to install AHCI drivers in Windows or it will not boot after changing the SATA mode.

Comment: Well, since it is not booting any OS now, I can't boot to Win10 now. What can I do in this situation?

Comment: Windows should boot but you probably need to select it at UEFI settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the actual issue. It is mainly BIOS setup for the latest model laptops comes with UEFI and secure boot options. I had to follow the following options:

1. select UEFI enable it
2. Secure boot disable it.
3. QuickBoot/FastBoot disable it.
4. Intel Smart Response Technology (SRT) disable it.
5. SATA has multiple options. RAIDR, AHCI, etc. Select AHCI mode.

Then boot the Linux infestation by DVD or USB. Well, the latest laptop comes without any CD/DVD ROM.

Now you should see the whole SSD. To verify it just lunch GParted. Thanks to GabrielaGarcia for helpful suggestions.